# Is there a way to disable indoors streetview from the default google maps api streetview

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

I could not find this in the Google Maps JavaScript API reference, so I ask here. Is there a way to disable the indoors part of the Street View when the pegman is dropped? I want only to be able to look around on the outdoors.

[image: Example]

On the picture above it is shown what I want to disable.

The example asked by geocodezip: jsfiddle.net/Dredd/5zgp0vdh

Comment: What does your code to display the StreetView look like? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 2):

To disable indoor street view use the option: `{source: google.maps.StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR}` in the [StreetViewLocationRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewLocationRequest)

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewLocationRequest):

> source | Type:  StreetViewSource
>
> Specifies the source of panoramas to search. This allows a restriction to search for just outdoor panoramas for example. If not specified it is set to DEFAULT.

[available values for StreetViewSource](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewSource)

> **DEFAULT**   Uses the default sources of Street View, searches will not be limited to specific sources.
>
> **OUTDOOR**   Limits Street View searches to outdoor collections. Indoor collections are not included in search results. Note also that the search only returns panoramas where it's possible to determine whether they're indoors or outdoors. For example, PhotoSpheres are not returned because it's unknown whether they are indoors or outdoors.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, but I think this is not what i am looking for. StreetViewLocationRequest is used by google.maps.StreetViewService. My implementation of the map is this:
https://jsfiddle.net/ebxxogf4/

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue **in the question itself.**

Comment: Hello, this is the example you ask for https://jsfiddle.net/Dredd/5zgp0vdh/
You can take the pegmen and drop in on a blue or orange dot and you go to streetview indoors, I want this to be not possible.

Comment: even if it's not the answer to the question, it helped me. thanks !